# How do I fix the syntax error with a list below

Tags: python, list, variables

```
config = [
    'description': 'My Project',
    'author': 'Aliyyah',
    'url': 'URL to get it at.',
    'download_url': 'Where to download it.',
    'author_email': '***@gmail.com',
    'version': '0.1',
    'install_requires': ['nose'],
    'packages': '['ex47'],
    'scripts': [],
    'name': 'ex47'
]
```

Every time I try setting a list to a variable like this, I always get a syntax error. I will appreciate if anyone knows what could be wrong, and how I can fix it.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and put there the syntax error you get? Also, I recommend to remove the e-mail from the question.

Comment: A **list** is not a **dictionary**, so you can't use `key: value`.

Comment: Further more, just observe the syntax highlighting, it should be pretty apparent places where it doesn't match highlighting in previous rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot declare a list like this. A list consists of only items that are separated by a comma. What you are trying to declare looks like a hash (or dict in Python). Please try to replace the square brackets with curly brackets, so it looks like this:

```
config = {
    'description': 'My Project',
    'author': 'Aliyyah',
    'url': 'URL to get it at.',
    'download_url': 'Where to download it.',
    'author_email': '***@gmail.com',
    'version': '0.1',
    'install_requires': ['nose'],
    'packages': ['ex47'],
    'scripts': [],
    'name': 'ex47'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error is caused by the square brackets around the packages value.

```
config = {
'description': 'My Project',
'author': 'Aliyyah',
'url': 'URL to get it at.',
'download_url': 'Where to download it.',
'author_email': '********@gmail.com',
'version': '0.1',
'install_requires': ['nose'],
'packages': 'ex47',
'scripts': [],
'name': 'ex47'
}
```